# How do you find the Inverse of Elliptic Integral of Second Kind when modulus is large

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion, approximation

So I tried to take the inverse of EllipticE when modulus is large,  in Mathematica,  but the solution gives wrong answer.

```
InverseSeries[Series[EllipticE[x, -k], {x, 0, 12}, {k, Infinity, 1}],y] = InverseFunction[y,k]
```

For example, I tried `EllipticE[0.5,-9.9] = 0.656` where `x:0.5 , k:-9.9, y:0.656`

But InverseFunction[y,k] is not equal to 0.5. Am I not correctly taking the inverse of the function?
I need a general form of an equation for the inverse of EllipticE. Polynomial approximation is also fine. The approximation should definitely work around when `x-->0` and `k-->-infinity`. 
So for the above example, the approximation function result should yield to 0.5 when y=0.656 and k=-9.9. I need to code this function in MCU, so I need an analytical approximation.

Caner

Comment: There may not exist  a good approximation for the two cases $x\to 0$ and $x\to \infty$ simultaneously.

Comment: I am more interested when x goes to zero and -k goes to infinity.
so like EllipticE[0.1,-600], EllipticE[0.05,-600]

Answer (score 1):

You can always do this if you are not tied to a series:

```
f = InverseFunction[EllipticE[#1, -9.9] &]

f[.656025]
(*0.5*)
```

or

```
g = InverseFunction[Function[{x, y}, EllipticE[x, y]], 1, 2]

g[.656025, -9.9]
(*0.5*)
```

This series works for smaller `x`

Clear[k]

```
f[x_, k_] = InverseSeries[Series[EllipticE[x, k], {x, 0, 20}]] // Simplify // Normal

k = -9.9;

f[.1, k]
(*0.0984504*)

EllipticE[%, k] // Chop
(*0.1*)

k = -50;

f[.1, k]
(*0.0935462*)

EllipticE[%, k] // Chop
(*0.0999678*)
```

The series still blows up for an `x` value as high as 0.656, so I guess it is a numerical issue and will probably require many more terms in the series with much higher precision than is practical. For smaller values of `x` this seems to give a decent approximation.

Comment: How do you make it parametric? I need a function or a series to code it directly.

Comment: I believe I have coded `f` to be a function.  Maybe you will like the function `g` I have added to my answer better.  But I guess I don't know how you plan to use it.

Comment: What i mean is, i need to have a parametric function or expression so that i can use it outside of mathematica. İt can be a powerseries, taylor series or any other parametric function.

Comment: The code `f = InverseFunction[EllipticE[#1, -x] &];Series[f[x], {x, 0, 2}]` produces $x+O\left(x^3\right)$.

Comment: I dont understand what this answer is. So what is the inverse of EllipticE[x,-k]  according to this notation?